# ConsoleTraceListener missing from Mono System.Diagnostics?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add a standard `ConsoleTraceListener` (in `System.Diagnostics`) as follows in Xamarin.iOS:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

I see this class defined on [Github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/ConsoleTraceListener.cs), in the [documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener) but its missing from the [Assembly Browser](http://safwanc.com/public/so/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-08%20at%202.43.35%20PM.png) in Xamarin Studio as well. My project is referencing `System.dll` v2.0.5.0.

In fact, only `TraceListener` and `DefaultTraceListener` are defined. Why is it missing and how can I fix this?

Comment: Also want to point out that `TextWriterTraceListener`, `EventLogTraceListener`, `DelimitedListTraceListener` and `XmlWriterTraceListener` are also missing.

Comment: Did anybody have confirmation of this ? I also get the error that Listeners does not exist in the context of Trace.